# org-capture + mu4e failures

Tags: org-mode, mu4e, org-capture

I'm trying to get org-capture and mu4e working together nicely. Org-capture is already correctly set up; I can capture links to source code files with the following template:

```
(setq org-capture-templates
          '(("t" "Todo" entry (file+headline "" "General To-Dos")
             "** TODO %?\n %i\n %A\n")))
```

I'd like to capture links to emails in `mu4e`. I have `org-mu4e` required, and `org-capture-link` works as expected in the mu4e message view. Great so far.

Now, I try to use the same template to use org capture an email. This always fails with the error, `Capture abort: (args-out-of-range 99)` (The number varies; I assume this is a code point, but cannot get it to render as anything other than a fairly opaque number).

Using the debugger, I've traced this error to the following code block in `org-capture-fill-template`:

```
  ;; Simple %-escapes
  (goto-char (point-min))
  (while (re-search-forward "%\\([tTuUaliAcxkKInfF]\\)" nil t)
(unless (org-capture-escaped-%)
  (when (and initial (equal (match-string 0) "%i"))
    (save-match-data
      (let* ((lead (buffer-substring
            (point-at-bol) (match-beginning 0))))
    (setq v-i (mapconcat 'identity
                 (org-split-string initial "\n")
                 (concat "\n" lead))))))
  (replace-match (or (eval (intern (concat "v-" (match-string 1)))) "")
         t t)))
```

As best as I can tell, everything up to `replace-match` is working perfectly. The error occurs when `replace-match` tries to replace a template character (using any of the link characters `%a`, `%A`, `%l`) with the captured link to the mu4e message. Instead of correctly doing the replace, `args-out-of-range` is thrown. Normally, I'd assume there was no correctly set `match` for `replace-match` to act on -- but `match-string` returns a correct match result, as does inspecting the match in the debugger.

I'm using Emacs 24.5.1, Org 8.3.4, and mu4e 0.9.16. I've tried this on two different Macs and a Fedora 22 machine; the behavior is absolutely consistent.

Comment: 99 is probably the character 'c' (`(format "%c" 99)`). Does that ring a bell ? I'm not sure why `replace-match` would throw such an error though. Can you get a backtrace (toggle-debug-on-error) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To my overwhelming exasperation, the problem has turned out to be: `emoji-cheat-sheet-plus-display-mode`, and the order in which it was activated in org mode.

I had a hook like so:

```
(defun text-settings ()
  (emoji-cheat-sheet-plus-display-mode))

(add-hook 'org-mode-hook 'text-settings)
```

Somehow -- and I have *no idea* how -- this was causing the horrible `args-out-of-range` error above. Removing `emoji-cheat-sheet-plus-display-mode` from org has fixed everything.

In conclusion: how do computers even work?